# Pronunciation of the "p" in the words like "splatter", "splash", "split", "explain" in American accent?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, american-accent

In the words like "splatter", "splash", "split" and "explain" should I make an aspirated or an unaspirated "p" sound? I can't decide which way is correct. I need your help.

Answer (score 3):

Voiceless plosives /p/, /t/, & /k/ are not aspirated:

- after /s/ sound: "**s**platter," "**s**plash," "**s**plit," and "e**x**plain"
- at the end of words: fa**t**, ba**ck**

Aside from that, they are usually aspirated but not as strong as in Received Pronunciation (British).

Answer (score 2):

In most varieties of English, voiceless plosives (/p/, /t/, /k/) are aspirated when they are the whole of the onset of a syllable, but not when they are in a cluster at the onset of a syllable.

So /p/ is not aspirated in any of your examples. It is aspirated in "patter" (but not "platter" or "spatter") and "passion", "pit", and "impound".

For me (British English), it is not normally aspirated in "expand" though, and I think that is because I effectively pronounce it as "ek-spand"

Comment: Thank you. But this doesn't apply when /p/, /t/ and /k/ are the first letters in a cluster like in "secret", right? I should make an aspirated "k" sound in this word as far as I know. But in the word "excuse", I should make an unaspirated sound at the second "k" according to what you said, right? I always pronounce both "k"s in "excuse" as aspirated sounds actually. I need to change my way then. Also as far as I know if there is "r" after "t" like in "street", "stream" etc, we make an aspirated "t" sound as far as I can remember. Am I wrong?

Comment: Also for example in "hatred" the "t" is pronounced as an aspirated sound despite being a part of a cluster. Btw "street" sounds better to me when I don't aspirate the "t". But as I said I think I heard before that if there is "r" after "t", the "t" should be aspirated. What I heard seems to be wrong.

Comment: I also should aspirate the voiceless stops in the words like "apply", "atrocious" "apron" etc. too, shouldn't I? I hope somebody answers these. :)

Comment: Hmm, that's a bit misleading. Aspiration is just a period of devoiced vowel after a plosive. It's  caused by a lag in the vocal fold vibration starting up. There is no *aspiration* in *platter*, but there is of course devoicing of the /l/, which is basically the same thing - we just reserve the term *aspiration* for devoiced vowels. However, this does not happen when a plosive is preceded by an /s/ at the beginning of the syllable. In other words there'll be no aspiration in *spatter* and no devoicing of the /l/ in splatter.

Comment: @Araucaria Shouldn't the /p/ in "platter" be aspirated since it is the first letter of the syllable?

Comment: @DereMemo Effectively yes, but technically no. When the devoicing occurs in a consonant, like /l, r, w, j/ we don't call it 'aspiration', we just call it devoicing. It's only technically aspiration when the next sound is a vowel.

Comment: @Araucaria Thank you. Can you help me on this topic too if you have time? https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/153145/how-to-pronounce-a-voiceless-stop-when-its-at-the-end-of-a-word-which-is-behind

Comment: @Araucaria If a word ends with a voiceless stop and if the next word starts with a vowel, should I still make an unaspirated sound? Or do I have to make that unaspirated sound only if the next word starts with a consonant or if there is a punctuation after the word that ends with the voiceless stop? For example should I make the same unaspirated sound in the sentences like "This is kin**d** of crazy" (the /d/ of "kind) , "A hu**g** is what I need" (the /g/ of "hug"), "This cra**b** is furious" (the /b/ of "crab"), "All ho**p**e is gone" (the /p/ of "hope") etc.?

Comment: @DereMemo Well, the first three are voiced, so there won't be any aspiration there. We won't usually put any noticeable aspiration on the /p/ there even though it precedes a vowel.

Comment: @Araucaria Sorry I wrote it as "voiceless stop" accidentally. Ok. So both voiced and voiceless stops are usually unaspirated in English even when they are at the end of a word and when the next word starts with a vowel or when they are at the end of a syllable and the next syllable starts with a vowel then.

Comment: By the way you said that stop consonants were always unaspirated at the ends of syllables in your older post, but this is completely wrong to me. As a person who has been listening to Americans for a quite long time, I can say that many Americans quite often aspirate the stop consonants if they are the last sounds of words. Especially in the words which are like the last words of clauses or the only words of clauses. I guess Americans can often make unaspirated sounds in the middle of words often and when the words which end with stop consonants are in the middles or the beginnings of se

Comment: ntences. What is your comment on this?

Comment: @DereMemo I  think you might be confusing aspirated stops with ejective ones.

Comment: I don't know what "ejective" is. :) I am from Turkey and I hear Americans make  those sounds in the positions I mentioned quite the same as I do in Turkish by releasing the air. I actually am not sure if I ever don't release the air when I pronounce those /k, p, t, g, b, d/ in my native language. People mostly can't notice those details in their own languages you know :)

Comment: I got one more problem. Some example phrases: "think of", "keep it", "kind of" "cube is", "and I". If those phrases were only one word as "thinkof", "keepit", "kindof" "cubis", "andye"  we would do the syllable division like this: /θɪŋ - kʌv/, /ki - pɪt/, /kaɪn - dʌv/, /kjuː - bɪz/ and /æn - daɪ/. That means we would aspirate the stops whether they are voiced or voiceless if we considered these phrases as one word. But you said that we shouldn't aspirate the stop sounds anyway at the ends of words.

Comment: But when I link a word whose last sound is a consonant with a word that starts with a vowel, I am used to pronouncing them as if they are one word. I was taught that way. So that in the phrases like "think of", "keep it", "kind of" ,"cop of", "cube is", "prank of", "youtube is", "and I" etc, I am used to pronouncing the stops at the ends of words as aspirated because of the syllable division I showed above.

Comment: But in the phrases like "book of", "crab is",  "hug is" etc. it is more natural for me to not to aspirate since the syllable division is like this when we think that they are one word: /bʊk - ʌv/,  /kræb - ɪz/ and /hʌɡ - ɪz/ etc. 
But I guess I am wrong, aren't I? I mean I shouldn't consider them as one word, right? Whatever the word that ends with a stop consonant is and whatever the next word that starts with a vowel is, I shouldn't aspirate the stop consonant?

Comment: @Araucaria Thank you for your answers. I am just asking for being confirmed. Whatever the next word that starts with a vowel or with a consonant is and whatever the word that ends with a stop is, I should make an unaspirated sound at the ends of words, right? So, in the phrases I gave in the second comment of mine after your last answer (in the phrases "kind of", "cube is", "and I" etc.), I should make an unaspirated sound anyway?