# How to pronounce a voiceless stop when it's at the end of a word which is behind a word that starts with a vowel?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, spoken-english, american-accent

I wonder if Americans usually make an unaspirated sound when the letters **"k"**, **"p"** or **"t"** is at the end of a word and when the next word starts with a vowel. I know that I should make a flap sound when there is a vowel or an "r" letter before "t" like in "See you a**t** eleven o'clock" and also I know that in the cluster "nt" Americans usually make an unaspirated sound like in "I can'**t** even", but what about other situations when "k", "p" and "t" are at the end of of a word which is behind a word that starts with a vowel? I mean in the sentences like

> - "I li**k**e animals"
> - "He is the best co**p** of the town",
> - "This is jus**t** unbelievable",
> - "He never liked roc**k** and roll",
> - "The aircraf**t** is descending",
> - "He never lik**ed** Arizona",
> - "This sho**p** is neat",
> - "And I was li**k**e 'I am not enjoying this'"

etc. do Americans usually make an unreleased stop sound? I feel like especially when they don't need to stress the word that ends with the voiceless stop, they usually don't aspirate the stop sound before a word that starts with a vowel. Am I right?

Comment: This is obviously going to vary by dialect, but in a sentence like "I like animals," I do aspirate the **k**, but it ends up being more attached to the following word, as if it were written, "I lie canimals."  Likewise with pretty much all of your other examples, with the exception of "And I was like 'I am not enjoying this,'" where my instinct is to sharply aspirate the **k** and stick in a brief pause before **I** so as to emphasize that a quote is beginning. (For reference, I grew up in the American northeast, now living in Canada.)

Comment: Bear in mind, English speakers do not "eat final" sounds, Spanish does. It there is one sound that  is  actually heard it is these final syllables on words with p, k or t. Otherwise, what is being said cannot be understood.  This shop is neat. You would not hear: This sho is neat. Or lie instead of like animals.The only one that might change is just. Some people will drop the t but they will drop it everywhere, not just when it is followed by a vowel sound.

Comment: They actually sound sort of like aspirated when they are not aspirated too. For example in the word "apple", the "p" shouldn't be aspirated; but when you aspirate it, it does sound similar to the unaspirated pronunciation of that word. The way I sound when I aspirate those voiceless stops in those example sentences is similar to the way I sound when I don't aspirate them. But when I don't aspirate them, it sounds more correct to me. And in the sentence "And I was like 'I am not enjoying this'", unlike you, for letting people understand that I am giving a quote, I make an unaspirated "k" sound.

Comment: Let me give you a concrete example: My husband is partially deaf. He was going around saying stree instead of street because he couldn't hear it. He is also a Spanish speaker. I had to teach him to "see" the t because he can't hear it in a work like street. An unvoiced final sound. The best co in town would never be heard. The p is always there; best cop in town. And it's best cop ***in town*** by the way.

Comment: @Lambie I am not talking about eating sounds. For example in the word "apple" the the /p/ is an unaspirated sound since it is the final sound of the syllable. Does it sound like it is eaten to you?

Comment: @DereMemo I will repeat: aspirated or not, those vowels are always pronounced otherwise the word could not be understood. /p/ has to be pronounced: ah-pull. So, without the /p/, there is no word. Just like all the other words you gave EXCEPT just which is at times pronounced without the t but not because of a vowel sound coming afterwards. Jus' saying. A Spanish person will tend to say: He never like Arizona. The d can get lost. Because Spanish does not have a lot of final vowel sounds. No, apple cannot sound like eaten. The intervocalic T's are another story. They are not at the end.

Comment: @Lambie Thank you but what you are saying is completely out of topic. I didn't ask if Americans don't pronounce them. There are two ways of pronouncing the sounds /k/, /p/ and /t/ in English. One is the aspirated way, the other one is the unaspirated way. Again, I am not asking if Americans don't pronounce them?

Comment: Intervocalic /t/ can change. Saturday becomes Sa-erday or Sadder-day. But the final sounds are always there,rock, shop, aircraft. etc.

Comment: You mean off-topic, not out of topic. And I am completely on topic.

Comment: No you are not. My question has nothing to do with not pronouncing a sound.

Comment: "I wonder if Americans usually make an unaspirated sound when the letters "k", "p" or "t" is at the end of a word": aspiration occurs via pronunciation, fyi.

Comment: You can pronounce a voiceless stop by not releasing the air too.

Comment: Personally, I don't think I ever make an unaspirated "k" even at the end of a word, despite being American. A terminal "p" or "t" may be unaspirated, but if I force myself to not aspirate a "k" at the end of a word, it feels very wrong.

Comment: Native English speakers usually can't notice if they aspirate or don't aspirate the voiceless stops in those situations as far as I know. So, if you didn't study on this subject, you might not exactly know if you actually aspirate them or not.

Comment: @CanadianYankee By " I don't think I ever make an unaspirated "k" even at the end of a word", you mean that you don't think that you aspirate the /k/ at the end of words even if the next word is starting with a consonant? As far as I know Americans mostly don't release the air when they pronounce /p,k,t/ at the ends of words if the next word in the clause is starting with a consonant. For example I bet you make an unaspirated /k/ sound when you say "Would you like to go home".

Answer (score 1):

As Canadian Yankee's comment says, the two words will simply blend together:

> - I lie k'animals.

Or will combine into one word:

> - The aircraft's descending.
> - That shop's neat.
> - He never liked rock'n roll.
> - This is just'unbelievable

and so on.

This varies with what you want to say.  You may want to emphasize a particular word, in which case it will sound separate from the following word.

> I would **like** a cat, but I don't really want'it.

When making speeches or other kinds of oration, it is advised to speak with good diction, and emphasize each word rather than slurring them together.  Obviously some public speakers have their own unique style and say what they want, but many will speak on stage (or on TV) differently from how they would speak in natural conversation.

This also varies by dialect.  Some are characterized by exaggerated diction, and those speakers might choose to make the two words completely separate.

Lastly, I wouldn't *try* to create this sound.  When you speak full sentences  fluently and quickly the natural cadences of English will force you to blend words together without thinking about it.

Comment: When I create that sound by making an unaspirated sound like the "p" sound in "apple" or like the "t" sound in "start", it sounds correct to me. I also heard from many English teachers that the voiceless stops should be unaspirated at the ends of syllables, but I didn't know much about the rule about the situations where the next word starts with a vowel.

Comment: In this video this channel claims that voiceless stops are usually pronounced as unaspirated at the ends of syllables. At 4:48. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yFPbLcUCraQ

Comment: For me, it does depend on whether there's a vowel sound following the syllable. If I just say "stop," then my mouth stays closed at the end of the word and there is no aspiration.  If I say "stop it," then the "p" is aspirated before the "i" as if it were the initial sound in the word "pit".  So while it's true that the "p" isn't aspirated at the *end* of a syllable, the "p" ends up migrating to be pronounced as the *initial* consonant of the following syllable if it starts with a vowel, and is thus aspirated.

Comment: When I don't aspirate it, it still sounds kind of like the initial letter of the next word but it sounds less stressed. So that it sounds more correct to me when I pronounce that way. For example in the words "apple", "clipper", "chopper" etc. the voiceless stops are unaspirated but they still sound as if they are the first sounds of the next syllable. Or in the words like "star", "scar", "storm" etc. the voiceless stops are unaspirated but since there is a vowel after them, they sound kind of like released.

Comment: So I think that the situation's the same when a word ends with a voiceless stop and the next word starts with a vowel. I think you guys actually usually don't release the sound, but because of the next sound, it sounds kind of like it is being released. I hope you can understand what I mean.

Comment: @DereMemo  Yes, perhaps, although again this can vary depending on who I'm speaking to and how fast.  Also again, I wouldn't worry about trying to reproduce this sound, as I feel it will come naturally once you speak English using the natural rhythms.  For example, in the sentence *"If you don't know where to stop it won't come out right"* there is a natural pause between "stop" and "it".  If you blur these together, it will sound like you're slurring your speech.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks. Yeah, since you are a native English speaker, you can naturally make most sounds properly if you are intellectual enough in terms of your language. But since I am not a native speaker, I think it is probably better if I be careful about that.